# Play framework: Query string bases session if cookie are disabled

Tags: session, playframework, playframework-2.0, cookieless

**Background: Why I need this:**
My application can be embed into iframe. By default safari browser on Mac have settings to disable third party cookies so effectively cookies are disabled for my app. I can not ask every one to allow third party cookies.

I need some way to authenticate requests even if cookie are blocked. Jetty  and tomcat provides query string based session, but after I moved to play framework i could not find any information about this. Please let me know if there is simple way where I do not have manage session by my own by parsing query string manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, you have to implement by your own.**

Play framework gives only stateless sessions out of box, which are stored on client side within cookies.

Just generate a token per user and send this token as a header value or as a query string parameter of every request and parse it on the server side to access session variables.

- You can also use some key/value storage or cache like memcached or redis to keep the session data.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to create my own implementation using Action composition as explained here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaActionsComposition
How can I read and modify response after getting Promise<Result> or Result

Comment: I have implemented it. a session wrapper to create and parse session query string.